# Swift - How implementing different ViewController/Class using swipe gesture?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I wonder how implementing two different ViewControllers and their own classes on the same page. Feed page both of them, and then I wanna pass them using left/right swipe gesture. But I don't know exactly how combining these pages together.

If someone explain as detailed It would be great.

[image]

> Update

[image]

I have added Bridging header and your lines of codes, after editing new ViewControllers and identifier. But When I run and open this view, application stopped with below error.

All my views WishVC, TestVC1, TestVC2 are blank, there are no object.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

Comment: Search in the Apple documentation for "view controller container".